# Conic shaped graticules?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules

Is there a way to enclose my conic shaped map in graticules on ArcMap? I can only figure out do this which doesn't look very nice: [image: Map]

I want something like this, I think this was done in GMT though: [image: map2]

Comment: Have you tried creating a feature class at the data perimeter, and symbolizing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the extent of your map by going on the layer properties > Data Frame > Clipping

There you can use one of your polygon with any shape and the graticule wil fit to this extent. In your case you need a rectangle drawn in a geographic coordinate system (densify its vertices before reprojecting to your conical projection)